# bind two arguments

Tags: c++, boost, bind, shared-ptr

Consider I have the following `struct`:

```
struct IDirect3D
{
    IDirect3D() : ref_count_(0) {}
    unsigned long Release() { return --ref_count_; }
private:
    long ref_count_;
    ~IDirect3D() {}
};
```

I want to use `shared_ptr` to it like in the followed code (minimal example):

```
int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<IDirect3D> ptr;

    IDirect3D* p = 0; // initialized somewhere
    ptr.reset( p, boost::mem_fn( &IDirect3D::Release ) );

    return 0;
}
```

This works OK in most cases, but crases if `p` in equal to `0`. I have the following deleter which I want to use:

```
template<typename T, typename D>
inline void SafeDeleter( T*& p, D d ) 
{ 
    if ( p != NULL ) {
        (p->*d)();
        p = NULL;
    }
}
```

But the following code gives a lot of error (looks like it dumps the whole `bind.hpp`):

```
ptr.reset( p, boost::bind( SafeDeleter, _1, &IDirect3D::Release ) );
```

What's wrong with my using of `bind`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Release()` comes from `IUnknown`- so why not just use that:

```
void my_deleter(IUnknown* p) {
    // ...
}

ptr.reset(p, &my_deleter);
```

Note that Boost also has an [`intrusive_ptr`](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) which would seem more natural here:

```
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(IUnknown* p) { p->AddRef (); }
void intrusive_ptr_release(IUnknown* p) { p->Release(); }

boost::intrusive_ptr<IDirect3D> d3d(...);
IDirect3D* p = 0;
d3d.reset(p);
```

Your actual issue is probably that there is a non-template function `SafeDeleter` - to specifically use the template-function you'd have to use something like:

```
ptr.reset(p, boost::bind(&SafeDeleter<IDirect3D, ULONG (IDirect3D::*)()>, 
                         _1, &IDirect3D::Release));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But expression with `bind` looks awful with template arguments. Better I'll just write my own deleter that will invoke `Release`.

Comment: @Kirill: According to the [documented effects](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html#Members) of ctor/dtor/`reset()` i don't see why that check is neccessary. *(sorry for the undecided back-and-forth-rolling)*